# Is there too wide a board to use for an end grain cutting board?

Tags: cutting-board

I'm making a 1.5" thick end grain cutting board with the attached design. Using maple, walnut, and cherry. The wider maple portion on the end could be done using a 6" wide piece of maple, or I could cut 3, 2" strips.

Is one choice better than the other for warping in a cutting board? Is it purely visual? The 2" strips will give a slight checkerboard pattern vs the bigger 6" pieces. Any other considerations?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can I just check, the wide maple section at right you hope to make up using multiple slices from a 6" wide board?

Comment: Purely on a visual basis I prefer end-grain boards that use pieces of fairly uniform size but I don't know that there will always be a sound reason to prefer to use smaller pieces (or at least consistently sized pieces, not necessarily small). I suspect it's going to come down to the individual boards used at the end of the day. If for example your 6" board is prone to warping it will still have some of that instability when cut into slices. But cut up into small blocks, especially with alternating blocks rotated 90 or 180°, that same wood will be more likely to be stable... [contd]

Comment: ...plus each glue line adds strength because glue joints (when done well) are stronger than wood.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yup, I’ll cut it up as you’re right, the look wouldn’t be the same. I sort of forgot about that!